# Obtener valor de un HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hola estoy haciendo un ejercicio en java para clases y no soy capaz de hacer que funciones el método consultarDepartamento. Yo en la clase donde tengo el main, tengo hecho un menú donde le pido el número del departamento que está en la clase Empleado. Todo el rato me sale el mensaje de que no existe el departamento cuando sí existe ya que estoy haciendo una conexión con una base de datos. En una parte del main de su menú tengo esto.

```
public interface Constantes {
String NOMBRE_SOCIEDAD = "Editex, S.A.";
Calendar FECHA_LIQUIDACION = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 5, 15);
double SALARIO_BASE = 735.90;
Calendar FECHA_CONVENIO = new GregorianCalendar(1985, 0, 1);
```

}

---

```
public abstract class Empleado {

private int numeroEmpleado;
private String nombreEmpleado;
private Calendar fechaIngreso;
private double salario;
private double comision;
private int porcentaje;
private Departamento departamento;
private int numcat;

public Empleado(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    this.numeroEmpleado = numeroEmpleado;
    this.nombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado;
    setFechaIngreso(fechaIngreso);
    setSalario(salario);
    setComision(comision);
    this.departamento = departamento;
    this.numcat = numcat;
    setPorcentaje();
}

/**
 * @return the numeroEmpleado
 */
public int getNumeroEmpleado() {
    return numeroEmpleado;
}

/**
 * @return the nombreEmpleado
 */
public String getNombreEmpleado() {
    return nombreEmpleado;
}

/**
 * @return the fechaIngreso
 */
public Calendar getFechaIngreso() {
    return fechaIngreso;
}

/**
 * @return the salario
 */
public double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

/**
 * @return the comision
 */
public double getComision() {
    return comision;
}

/**
 * @return the porcentaje
 */
public int getPorcentaje() {
    return porcentaje;
}

/**
 * @return the departamento
 */
public Departamento getDepartamento() {
    return departamento;
}

/**
 * @return the numcat
 */
public int getNumcat() {
    return numcat;
}

/**
 * @param numeroEmpleado the numeroEmpleado to set
 */
public void setNumeroEmpleado(int numeroEmpleado) {
    this.numeroEmpleado = numeroEmpleado;
}

/**
 * @param nombreEmpleado the nombreEmpleado to set
 */
public void setNombreEmpleado(String nombreEmpleado) {
    this.nombreEmpleado = nombreEmpleado;
}

/**
 * @param fechaIngreso the fechaIngreso to set
 */
public void setFechaIngreso(Calendar fechaIngreso) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    if (fechaIngreso.compareTo(Constantes.FECHA_CONVENIO) >= 0) {
        this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    } else {
        throw new FechaIngresoFueraConvenio("El empleado núm:" + getNumeroEmpleado() + ", " + getNombreEmpleado() + " tiene una fecha de ingreso, fuera de convenio: " + fechaIngreso.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}

/**
 * @param salario the salario to set
 */
public void setSalario(double salario) {

    if (salario < Constantes.SALARIO_BASE) {
        salario = Constantes.SALARIO_BASE;
    } else {
        this.salario = salario;
    }
}

/**
 * @param comision the comision to set
 */
public void setComision(double comision) {

    if (comision > getSalario()) {
        comision = getSalario();
    } else {
        this.comision = comision;
    }
}

/**
 * @param porcentaje the porcentaje to set
 */
public void setPorcentaje() {
    int anio = (int) Math.floor((Constantes.FECHA_LIQUIDACION.getTimeInMillis() - fechaIngreso.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
    this.porcentaje = anio;
}

/**
 * @param departamento the departamento to set
 */
public void setDepartamento(Departamento departamento) {
    this.departamento = departamento;
}

/**
 * @param numcat the numcat to set
 */
public void setNumcat(int numcat) {
    this.numcat = numcat;
}

public double calcularLiquidacion() {
    double total = (getSalario() + getComision()) * (getPorcentaje() / 100.0);
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("Núm %2d %-18s %-45s", getNumeroEmpleado(), getNombreEmpleado(), getDepartamento().toString());
}
```

}

---

```
public class EmpleadoBase extends Empleado {

private double pagas;

public EmpleadoBase(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat, double pagas) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    super(numeroEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, fechaIngreso, salario, comision, departamento, numcat);
    this.pagas = pagas;
}

public double calcularLiquidacion() {
    double total = pagas + super.calcularLiquidacion();
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return "EMPLEADO BASE " + super.toString() + " LIQUIDACIÓN " + this.calcularLiquidacion() + "\n";
}
```

}

---

```
public class Comercial extends Empleado{
 private double pagas;

public Comercial(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat, double pagas) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    super(numeroEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, fechaIngreso, salario, comision, departamento, numcat);
    this.pagas = pagas;
}

public double calcularLiquidacion(){
    double total = pagas+super.calcularLiquidacion();
    return total;
}

public String toString(){
    //return "EMPLEADO BASE " + super.toString()+ " LIQUIDACIÓN " + this.calcularLiquidacion()+"\n";
    return String.format("COMERCIAL %-18s LIQUIDACION %2s\n", super.toString(), this.calcularLiquidacion());
}
```

}

---

```
public class Directivo extends Empleado {

private double pagas;
private double plusDireccion;

public Directivo(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat, double pagas) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    super(numeroEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, fechaIngreso, salario, comision, departamento, numcat);
    this.pagas = pagas;
    setPlusDireccion();
}

public void setPlusDireccion() {
    plusDireccion = (getComision() + getSalario()) * 0.25;
}

public double calcularLiquidacion() {
    double total = pagas + super.calcularLiquidacion() + plusDireccion;
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return "DIRECTIVO " + super.toString() + " LIQUIDACIÓN " + this.calcularLiquidacion() + "\n";
}
```

}

---

```
public class Ejecutivo extends Empleado {

private double pagas;

public Ejecutivo(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat, double pagas) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    super(numeroEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, fechaIngreso, salario, comision, departamento, numcat);
    this.pagas = pagas;
}

public double calcularLiquidacion() {
    double total = pagas + super.calcularLiquidacion();
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return "EJECUTIVO " + super.toString() + " LIQUIDACION: " + this.calcularLiquidacion() + "\n";
}
```

}

---

```
public class Tecnico extends Empleado {

private double pagas;
private String tipoTecnico;

public Tecnico(int numeroEmpleado, String nombreEmpleado, Calendar fechaIngreso, double salario, double comision, Departamento departamento, int numcat, double pagas) throws FechaIngresoFueraConvenio {
    super(numeroEmpleado, nombreEmpleado, fechaIngreso, salario, comision, departamento, numcat);
    this.pagas = pagas;
    setTipoTecnico();
}

/**
 * @param tipoTecnico the tipoTecnico to set
 */
public void setTipoTecnico() {
    if (super.getNumcat() == 2) {
        tipoTecnico = "AUXILIAR";
    } else if (getNumcat() == 3) {
        tipoTecnico = "ESPECIALISTA";
    }
}

public double calcularLiquidacion() {
    double total = pagas + super.calcularLiquidacion();
    return total;
}

public String toString() {
    return "TECNICO " + tipoTecnico + " " + super.toString() + " LIQUIDACION: " + this.calcularLiquidacion() + "\n";
}
```

}

---

```
public class Departamento {
private int numeroDepartamento;
private String nombreDepto;
private String nombreCentro;

public Departamento(int numeroDepartamento, String nombreDepto, String nombreCentro) {
    this.numeroDepartamento = numeroDepartamento;
    this.nombreDepto = nombreDepto;
    this.nombreCentro = nombreCentro;
}

public int getNumeroDepartamento() {
    return numeroDepartamento;
}

public void setNumeroDepartamento(int numeroDepartamento) {
    this.numeroDepartamento = numeroDepartamento;
}

public String getNombreDepto() {
    return nombreDepto;
}

public void setNombreDepto(String nombreDepto) {
    this.nombreDepto = nombreDepto;
}

public String getNombreCentro() {
    return nombreCentro;
}

public void setNombreCentro(String nombreCentro) {
    this.nombreCentro = nombreCentro;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[" + nombreDepto + "(" + nombreCentro+")" + ']';
}
```

}

---

```
public class FechaIngresoFueraConvenio extends Exception{
public FechaIngresoFueraConvenio(String msg){
    super(msg);
}
```

}

---

```
public class Liquidacion {

private HashMap<Integer, Empleado> plantilla = new HashMap<Integer, Empleado>();

public void insertaEmpleado(int numero, Empleado empleado) {
    plantilla.put(numero, empleado);
}

public String consultaEmpleado(int numero) {
    String mensaje = "";
    double acumulador = 0.0;//acumular la liquidacion
    boolean encontrado = false;

    Set<Integer> numeros = plantilla.keySet();
    Iterator<Integer> it = numeros.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer num = it.next();
        if (plantilla.get(num).getNumeroEmpleado() == numero) {
            acumulador += plantilla.get(num).calcularLiquidacion();
            mensaje += plantilla.get(num).toString();
            encontrado = true;
        }
    }

    if (encontrado) {
        return mensaje;
    } else {
        return String.format("No existe el empleado o está fuera del convenio");
    }

}

public String consultaDepartamento(int numero) {
    String mensaje = "LIQUIDACION POR DEPARTAMENTO\n";
    double acumulador = 0.0;//acumular la liquidacion
    boolean encontrado = false;

    Set<Integer> numeros = plantilla.keySet();
    Iterator<Integer> it = numeros.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer num = it.next();
        if (plantilla.get(num).getDepartamento().getNumeroDepartamento() == numero) {
            acumulador += plantilla.get(num).calcularLiquidacion();
            mensaje += plantilla.get(num).toString();
            encontrado = true;
        }
        //System.out.println("debug: "+plantilla.get(num).getDepartamento().getNumeroDepartamento());
    }


    if(encontrado){
        return mensaje.toString() +"\nTOTAL:"+acumulador+"\nFIN DE LISTADO DEPARTAMENTO";
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}

public String consultaPlantilla() {
    String listadoPlantilla = null;
    Double acumulador = 0.0;
    listadoPlantilla = "LIQUIDACION: Editex, S.A.\n";
    Set<Integer> numeros = plantilla.keySet();
    Iterator<Integer> it = numeros.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer num = it.next();
        acumulador += plantilla.get(num).calcularLiquidacion();
        listadoPlantilla += plantilla.get(num).toString() + "\n";
    }

    return listadoPlantilla += "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTOTAL EMPRESA: " + acumulador + "\n" + "****FIN LISTADO EMPRESA****";
}
```

}

---------------MAIN-------------------

```
public class Aplicacion {

static Empleado empleado = null;
static Liquidacion liquidacion = new Liquidacion();
static Departamento departamento = null;
static Date fechin;
static Calendar fechaIngreso = Calendar.getInstance();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conexion = null;
    //Creamos un objeto de tipo Statement
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        // Base de datos a la que vamos a conectar
        String BaseDeDatos = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        // Establecer la conexión
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(BaseDeDatos, "DAW1", "DAW1");

        //CONSULTA
        stm = conexion.prepareStatement("select e.numemple, e.nomemple, e.fechin, e.salario, e.comision, p.julio, p.navidad, c.nomce, d.numdepto, d.nomdepto, p.numcat "
                + "from empleado e, paga p, departamento d, centro c "
                + "where e.numcat=p.numcat and d.numce = c.numce");
        rset = stm.executeQuery();

        while (rset.next()) {
            fechin = rset.getDate(3);
            fechaIngreso.setTime(fechin);
            double pagas = (rset.getDouble(6) + rset.getDouble(7)) / 2;
            departamento = new Departamento(rset.getInt(9), rset.getString(10), rset.getString(8));

            try {
                if (rset.getInt(11) == 1) {
                    empleado = new EmpleadoBase(rset.getInt(1), rset.getString(2), fechaIngreso, rset.getDouble(4), rset.getDouble(5), departamento, rset.getInt(11), pagas);
                }
                if (rset.getInt(11) == 2 || rset.getInt(11) == 3) {
                    empleado = new Tecnico(rset.getInt(1), rset.getString(2), fechaIngreso, rset.getDouble(4), rset.getDouble(5), departamento, rset.getInt(11), pagas);
                }
                if (rset.getInt(11) == 4 || rset.getInt(11) == 5) {
                    empleado = new Ejecutivo(rset.getInt(1), rset.getString(2), fechaIngreso, rset.getDouble(4), rset.getDouble(5), departamento, rset.getInt(11), pagas);
                }
                if (rset.getInt(11) == 6) {
                    empleado = new Comercial(rset.getInt(1), rset.getString(2), fechaIngreso, rset.getDouble(4), rset.getDouble(5), departamento, rset.getInt(11), pagas);
                }
                if (rset.getInt(11) == 7) {
                    empleado = new Directivo(rset.getInt(1), rset.getString(2), fechaIngreso, rset.getDouble(4), rset.getDouble(5), departamento, rset.getInt(11), pagas);
                }
            } catch (FechaIngresoFueraConvenio e) {
            }

            liquidacion.insertaEmpleado(rset.getInt(1), empleado);

        }

        Menu();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            conexion.close();
            stm.close();
            rset.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

private static void Menu() {
    int opcion = 0;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        System.out.println("Editex, S.A. Consulta liquidaciones:\n"
                + "1. Empleado\n"
                + "2. Departamento\n"
                + "3. Plantilla\n"
                + "4. Salir\n"
                + "Elige la opción (1/2/3/4).");
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Inserte el número del empleado");
                int numero = entrada.nextInt();

                System.out.println(liquidacion.consultaEmpleado(numero));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Inserte el número de departamento");
                int numeroDepto = entrada.nextInt();

                System.out.println(liquidacion.consultaDepartamento(numeroDepto));
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println(liquidacion.consultaPlantilla());
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Has salido de la apliacion");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opción incorrecta");
        }
    } while (opcion != 4);
}
```

}

Comment: Bueno hay varias cosas. Si el `HashMap` tiene varios elementos, dado que lo estás recorriendo en un bucle, `encontrado` se quedará solamente con la última evaluación que ocurra dentro del `HashMap`, de modo que este código no resolverá tu problema. Una posible solución sería, en cada paso dentro del bucle, agregar otra clave al `HashMap` con el valor `true` o `false` de encontrado, así podrás saber de cada elemento del `HashMap` si se encontró o no. Si lo que quieres es verificar si el departamento se halla en al menos un elemento,  entonces debes salir del bucle en cuanto encuentre uno.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido, pero casi no me he enterado de nada, acabo de empezar con java por así decirlo y soy penoso programando. Te explico un poco mejor. En la clase Empleado tengo una variable Departamento que a su vez es otra clase donde hay 3 variables y una de ellas el número del departamento. No sé cómo ir agregando otra clave en el HashMap. Incluso recorriéndolo con un for básico, tampoco me funciona.

Comment: ¿Podrías imprimir el resultado de esto en cada paso del bucle, fuera del `if` no dentro: `System.out.println("debug: "+plantilla.get(num).getDepartamento().getNumeroDepartamento());`

Comment: Sale todo el rato 140, que me imagino que será el número de un departamento

Comment: Y el 140 será el resultado del `toString` del `Empleado` que encuentras con el `get`.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo de lo que se me pide que haga en el ejercicio. Por lo que he estado viendo, si meto el 140, que es el número de un departamento, me saca todos los empleados, incluyendo los de un departamento diferente. Cuando lo que quiero es que sólo salgan los de ese departamento.

Comment: El que el código original parezca correcto, que el "ejemplo" funcione y que hayas añadido código me hace pensar en que quizás no tengas claro de dónde viene el fallo. Intenta limitar el ámbito del error; p.ej. imprime los valores que obtienes de la BD para asegurarte que realmente tienes los valores que esperas; o usa valores fijos creados por programa para probar tu algoritmo independientemente de la BD.

Comment: No sé de donde viene el fallo. La base de datos, imprime los valores correctos, ya he hecho la prueba. Pero gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes un error de concepto con los HashMap, viendo tu código al ejecutar `plantilla.put(numero, empleado);` por ejemplo:

```
plantilla.put(1, a)
plantilla.put(1, b)
plantilla.put(2, c)
plantilla.put(2, d)
plantilla.put(2, e)
```

Supuestamente tendría una plantilla de 5 empleados donde para el departamento 1 tendría a,b y para el 2 tendría c,d,e.

Pero no es así, tu resultado será solo una plantilla de dos empleados el b,e. Ya que son los últimos elementos y al hacer `plantilla.put(2, e)` machacas el empleado que existía anteriormente para ese key "2" por el nuevo (e).

Te paso un código simple donde puedes ver como trabajo con el HashMap de la manera que esperas que lo haga.

Donde la clave del asunto está en :  `HashMap<Integer, List<Empleado>> plantilla = new HashMap<Integer, List<Empleado>>();` de esta manera tienes un listado de empleados por departamento que es lo que te interesa.

```
public class Borrar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Se crea la estructura Plantilla que tiene departamentos y listado de empleados por departamento
        HashMap<Integer, List<Empleado>> plantilla = new HashMap<Integer, List<Empleado>>();

        //Variable Para nombrar a los empleados: Empleado-1, Empleado-2...
        int empleadosCreados = 1; 

        // Inicialización de la PLANTILLA
        // Creo 3 Departamentos
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            // A cada departamento le añado 4 empleados
            List<Empleado> empleados= new ArrayList<Empleado>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                Empleado e = new Empleado();
                e.setNombre("Empleado-" + empleadosCreados);
                empleadosCreados++;
                empleados.add(e);
            }
            plantilla.put(i, empleados);
        }

        // En este punto tengo 3 departamentos de 4 empleados con una plantilla total de 12

        //Plantilla
        for (Entry<Integer, List<Empleado>> entry : plantilla.entrySet()) {
            List<Empleado> empleadosPorDepartamento = entry.getValue();
            for (Empleado empleado : empleadosPorDepartamento) {
                System.out.println(empleado.getNombre());
            }
        }

        //Departamento del departamento 1
        List<Empleado> empleadosPorDepartamento= plantilla.get(1);
        for (Empleado empleado : empleadosPorDepartamento) {
            System.out.println(empleado.getNombre());
        }

    }
```

Resultado:

```
Plantilla completa:
Empleado-1
Empleado-2
Empleado-3
Empleado-4
Empleado-5
Empleado-6
Empleado-7
Empleado-8
Empleado-9
Empleado-10
Empleado-11
Empleado-12
Empleados del departamento 1: 
Empleado-5
Empleado-6
Empleado-7
Empleado-8
```

Comment: Al añadir empleados no se machacan ninguno, ya que la key el primary key de la base de datos que es a su vez el número de empleado. Después en los valores que están en la clase Empleado está el departamento. Voy a subir todas las clases. A mi me da que el error está en la clase con el main, pero no consigo verlo. Gracias.

Comment: Vale, ahora mirando más en detalle veo lo que estas haciendo, y el código parece estar correcto puedes detallarme cual es el fallo que te sale ¿El departamento no existe en la Plantilla porque no lo has encontrado al recorrer todos los empleados.? Pregunta: ¿Que diferencia tiene tu hashMap a una Lista si cada vez que te pidan algún elemento tienes que recorrerla entera?
Cuando dices que crees que el error está en el main te refieres a cuando cargas la información el la Plantilla o cuando seleccionas la opción en el menú?. Son muchas preguntas, pero creo que pueden ayudar a encontrar tu error.

Comment: Como debug te puede ayudar imprimirte todos los departamentos y ver si el que estás pasando en el menú existe, o directamente buscarlo:
for (Entry<Integer, Empleado> entry : Liquidacion.getPlantilla.entrySet()) {
   Empleado empleado = entry.getValue();
   if (empleado.getDepartamento().getNumeroDepartamento() == 1)
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().getNombre());
  }
Puedes poner este código justo después de hacer la carga de BBDD. Si le creas un método get al atributo plantilla.

Comment: Respondiendo a tus preguntas:
1º Hay varios departamentos, 110, 135....y el último es el 140. Lo cual si en la opción de introducir en el main el número de departamento, introduzco el 110, sale null, pero si pongo 140 saca todos los empleados de todos los departamentos.
2º El ejercicio (el UML) vienen con el HashMap como variable de la clase liquidación, y por lo que nos mostró el profesor, lo tengo como él lo explicó.
3º Creo que el error está en el main, creo que está cuando se carga la información dentro del while(rset.next).

Voy a intentar comprobar lo que me has dicho del debug

Comment: Ya he puesto como debug lo que me has dicho, y si por ejemplo pongo el departamento número 135 me aparece MARKETING, si por ejemplo pongo el número  120, sale ORGANIZACION. Es decir, funcionar funciona y la sentencia sql está bien.

Comment: Al final el programa funciona perfectamente. Mi profesor lo ejecutó en su PC y le iba, no tuvo, ni tuve, que cambiar código. Quizás fuera por alguna mala conexión entre mi máquina virtual y la base de datos.

Comment: Me alegro, le di un par de vueltas y no había manera de sacarte el error. Es bueno saber que no existía XD. Un saludo.